# Next.js warn : ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, dependencies, babeljs

I have a Next.js project that has some pages written in plain JS. A colleague added some testing for TS, but no TS used for the pages and the components yet.

I fetch the files out of a git repo and do `npm install` and then `npm run dev`

After the `npm run dev` I get

```
./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

If I try to access `localhost:3000` is blank and in the terminal I also get

```
./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
warn  - ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
warn  - ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
warn  - ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
warn  - ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:584:53)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1007:6)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1806:2)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:143:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:24:15)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:66:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/link.js:1:18)
    at Object../node_modules/next/link.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:207:1)
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:584:53)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1007:6)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1806:2)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:143:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:24:15)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:66:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/link.js:1:18)
    at Object../node_modules/next/link.js (/home/nick/Documents/myproject/.next/server/pages/_app.js:207:1)
error - ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

My `package.json` file is

```
{ 
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 80",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.1",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.0.8",
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` file is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and `babel.config.js` is

```
module.exports = {
  presets:[
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Please help me fix this, I dont know how .

Thanks